# Storm Bolt not printing/logging Kafka Spout

Tags: java, apache-storm, apache-kafka

Edit: I added an .ack() to the Bolt (which required me to use a Rich Bolt instead of the basic bolt) and am having the same issue - nothing that tells me tuples are being processed by the bolt.

If it matters, I'm running this on a CentOS image on an EC2 instance. Any help would be appreciated.

---

---

I'm trying to set up a very basic HelloWorld Storm example to read messages from a Kafka cluster and print/log the messages I get.

Currently I have 20 messages in the Kafka cluster. When I run the topology (which appears to start just fine), I am able to see my Kafka Spout as well as the Echo Bolt.  In the Storm UI, the Kafka Spout `Acked` column has 20 as a value - which I would assume is the number of messages that it was able to read/access (?)

The Echo Bolt line, however, only notes that I have 1 executor and 1 tasks. All other columns are 0.

Looking at the Storm worker log that is generated, I see this line: `Read partition information from: /HelloWorld Spout/partition_0  --> {"topic":"helloworld","partition":0,"topology":{"id":"<UUID>","name":"Kafka-Storm test"},"broker":{"port":6667,"host":"ip-10-0-0-35.ec2.internal"},"offset":20}`

The next few lines are as follows:

```
s.k.PartitionManager [INFO] Last commit offset from zookeeper: 0
s.k.PartitionManager [INFO] Commit offset 0 is more than 9223372036854775807 behind, resetting to startOffsetTime=-2
s.k.PartitionManager [INFO] Starting Kafka ip-10-0-0-35.ec2.internal:0 from offset 0
s.k.ZkCoordinator [INFO] Task [1/1] Finished refreshing
s.k.ZkCoordinator [INFO] Task [1/1] Refreshing partition manager connections
s.k.DynamicBrokersReader [INFO] Read partition info from zookeeper: GlobalPartitionInformation{partitionMap={0=ip-10-0-0-35.ec2.internal:6667}}
```

The rest of the worker log shows no log/print out of the messages processed by the Bolt. I'm at a loss of why the Bolt doesn't seem to be getting any of the messages from the Kafka Cluster. Any help would be great. Thanks.

**Building the KafkaSpout**

```
private static KafkaSpout setupSpout() {
  BrokerHosts hosts = new ZkHosts("localhost:2181");
  SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(hosts, "helloworld", "", "HelloWorld Spout");
  spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
  spoutConfig.forceFromStart = true;
  spoutConfig.startOffsetTime = kafka.api.OffsetRequest.EarliestTime();
  return new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig);
}
```

**Building the topology and submitting it**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
  builder.setSpout("Kafka Spout", setupSpout());
  builder.setBolt("Echo Bolt", new SystemOutEchoBolt());

  try {
    System.setProperty("storm.jar", "/tmp/storm.jar");
    StormSubmitter.submitTopology("Kafka-Storm test", new Config(), builder.createTopology());
  } //catchExceptionsHere
}
```

**Bolt**

```
public class SystemOutEchoBolt extends BaseRichBolt {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SystemOutEchoBolt.class);

  private OutputCollector m_collector;

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  @Override
  public void prepare(Map _map, TopologyContext _conetxt, OutputCollector _collector) {
    m_collector = _collector;
  }

  @Override
  public void execute(Tuple _tuple) {
    System.out.println("Printing tuple with toString(): " + _tuple.toString());
    System.out.println("Printing tuple with getString(): " + _tuple.getString(0));
    logger.info("Logging tuple with logger: " + _tuple.getString(0));
    m_collector.ack(_tuple);
  }

  @Override
  public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer _declarer) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was simple. I was never telling the bolt which stream to subscribe to. Adding `.shuffleGrouping("Kafka Spout");` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call an ack or fail on the tuple in your bolts, otherwise the spout doesn't know that the tuple has been fully processed. This will cause the count issues you're seeing.

```
public class SystemOutEchoBolt extends BaseBasicBolt {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SystemOutEchoBolt.class);

  @Override
  public void execute(Tuple _tuple, BasicOutputCollector _collector) {
    System.out.println("Printing tuple with toString(): " + _tuple.toString());
    System.out.println("Printing tuple with getString(): " + _tuple.getString(0));
    logger.info("Logging tuple with logger: " + _tuple.getString(0));
    _collector.ack(_tuple);
  }

  @Override
  public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer arg0) {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I will give that a shot. It looks like I'll need to use a Rich Bolt because the BasicOutputCollector doesn't have a .ack() method.  This would probably solve my count issues, but will it also solve the issue of me not being able to see the log/print statements in the worker log file?